# How do you use php to communicate with App Inventors TinyWebDB component?

Tags: php

Google App Inventor has some information in their documentation for setting up a sample TinyWebDB webservice using python or app engine, however, I'm trying to use php.  Is this possible?  I've followed directions posted [here](http://www.greenhughes.com/content/passing-data-php-script-android-appinventor-application-using-tinywebdb) but all I get is the error:

> Communication with the web service
>   encountered a protocol exception

I display this error in a `label` component on the when `TinyWebDB1.WebServiceError` block.

So here is what I have in my php files:

**getvalue.php**

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2010 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$retval = array("VALUE", "tagged", '"'.time().'"'); 
echo json_encode($retval);
```

Which returns:

["VALUE","tagged","\"1283093117\""]

**setvalue.php**

```
$tag = $_POST['tag'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$retval = array("STORED", '"'.$tag.'"', '"'.$value.'"');
echo json_encode($retval);
```

Which returns:

["STORED","\"tagged\"","\"testdata\""]

Thanks for any suggestions or answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "setvalue", you should use "storeavalue"

Comment: I'll kick myself if it's that simple, how could I have missed that.  Will mark answer tonight if it works.

Comment: I honestly don't recall if this was it, but as AppInventor is no longer available and this is the only answer, I figured we may as well close this question with a marked answer.